# Why is shrinkwrap "sinking" under certain parts?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I want to unwrap the plane on the mesh to make spider net on the face and later on body.

I tried with the single vertex, with the curve line and now with the plane. I have taken the plane and sub divided by 30 and I added *Subsurface* modifier to get more sub division.

I added the *Shrinkwrap* modifier to it. The plane got shrinkwrapped in a good way to the lips and nose but creates problems on the neck and the head side.

What's going wrong with the shrinkwrap? I have tried the project tried negative positive direction and front back options and nearest surface point keeping the offset 0.01, but did not succeed.

Why is the shrinkwrap not wrapping cleanly on the neck side?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This *is* the expected behavior, Blender can't guess automatically how you want to wrap your mesh if it is not roughly following to the underlying surface

Answer (score 5):

What is happening here is the following.

You are using shrinkwrap with the "project" option.

In this case, the mesh is projected along its face's normals (the arrows in the image below)

Even if two points are close (like in -1-), their projection following the arrows (in -2-), makes a larger segment which is cut by Spiderman's face.

[image]

To obtain a better result (with less vertices), you should roughly follow the face curvature so that the projection can be done appropriately.

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying but sorry im not getting what you mean. Is there any other method which can work and wrap good way. Doing manually will take time.

Comment: @ateks, you know... sometimes we try to find the "clever approach" and spend a lot of time on it, but the subject simply needs "ants work"...

Comment: Roughly following curvature like you suggested (i.e. leaving the least amount of work for the Shrinkwrap to do) helped in my case. Thanks.