# How to wrap on the sphere like ornamental design

Tags: mesh

I have a default sphere and created ornamental design. I want to coil or wrap on the sphere. I tried shrinkwrap modifier but it did not work. Is there any other i can coil or wrap the design on the sphere.

[image]

[image]

Similar to like this

[image]

Below Aladdin lamp is my model and i want to wrap on that lamp.

[image]
Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Comment: Use two bend modifiers. 1st to bulge it so it's not flat and 2nd to turn it around the sphere. You will have to tune them to fit the sphere.

Comment: Your own questions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95975/why-im-not-getting-thickness-with-shrinkwrap-modifier and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74414/why-shrinkwrap-not-working-on-the-mesh and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77011/why-shrinkwrap-not-working-perfect and lot about Curve modifier I think many of those questions are perfect for answer this one.

Comment: @cgslav All the link posted of my question shrinkwrap modifier i want to make it unique way not manually with lattice

Comment: This is why I've also mentioned about your questions (and even answers) about Curve modifier. You can use combination of Curve and Shrinkwrap to make it even be completely nondestructive and perfectly aligned.

Comment: well, I've answered but you changed your question in the meantime, a small ornament on a big sphere is not the same as a big ornament on a small vase

Comment: Related or duplicates: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58276/how-can-i-project-text-around-a-sphere-using-shrinkwrap-modifier and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52904/wrap-curve-around-sphere and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36493/how-do-i-shrinkwrap-an-object-to-a-curved-surface-cleanly-and-efficiently and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/how-to-add-curve-modifier-to-text and so many more. C'mon all of them are from googling "blender shrinkwrap sphere" and there is more.

Comment: @cgslav i have edited the question plz read it. Below moonboots have answer but im not satisfied with the curve modifier he is using.

Comment: @atek look at all related links I have posted above. You have many different techniques there. For your case I would use probably shrinkwraped lattice or shrinkwraped curve. Everything is answered in links. Or maybe Mesh/Surface deform modifiers: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/mesh_deform.html  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/surface_deform.html

Comment: Do you really [need another question about Shrink Wraps](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A30601+shrinkwrap)? You have asked this question already countless times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) Curve Modifier**

For a simple sphere, I guess using the Curve modifier would be the best solution:

- Create a bezier curve with the same circumference as your sphere
- Add a modifier to your ornament and choose the curve as your Object in the modifier

[image]

**2) Surface Deform and Shrinkwrap modifiers**

But as your shape is much more complex than a simple sphere, perhaps you could use this method:

- Create a plane, subdivide it and place it behind your ornament,
- Give your ornament a *Surface Deform* modifier, choose the plane as the *Target*, and *bind* it so that the plane will deform the ornament as you want.
- Give to your plane a *Shrinkwrap* modifier, and choose your lamp as the *Target* so that the plane sticks to the shape and the ornament follows.
- Disable the eye icon in the *Shrinkwrap* modifier and shift D > duplicate both your plane and ornament all around your object, according to the direction of your shape's normals.
- Re-enable the eye icon for each *Shrinkwrap* modifier so that you can see the the ornaments sticking all around your shape.
- *Apply* the modifiers you want, delete the planes.
- As this method didn't use an array, your ornaments are not properly joined, if you need to do it, join them with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> and use some <kbd>W</kbd> > *Bridge*.

[image]

Comment: The sphere is just an example will that work that vase also same way

Comment: no you need to use a different technic, I'll try to find the best

Comment: @moonboots check my related links under the question.

Comment: i have edit my question i want that ornamental on my Aladdin lamp. Read the question plz